# How can I direct a pipe input to ls command?

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, pipe

When I type something like:

```
find . -name *foo* | ls -lah
```

it returns the same result as a plain `ls` command, as though it had no input.

However:

```
ls -lah $( find . -name *foo* )
```

works well, but only when the `find` command has results.

Is it possible to pipe to `ls` ?

Comment: You need to specify whether you want to ls the files inside each find result, or you want to ls the find results directly. If it is the latter, then u/Dennis's answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `-exec` with `find` command.

```
find . -name '*foo*' -exec ls -lah {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. There is no pipe but it's an elegant method. If there aren't found any results with 'find' it doesn't display anything (what is in fact good).

Comment: A slightly better way: `find . -name '*foo*' -exec ls -lah {} +`

Comment: I tried to find out why adding a `+` was better.  `man less` and searching for `-exec command {} +` found it.  Adding `+` to the end of the command multiple arguments to be appended before executing the command.  So much fewer commands are run.

Comment: According to the man page: "There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec  action;  you  should use the -execdir option instead." The option `-execdir` is similar to `-exec` but runs the command from the subdirectory containing the matched file.

Answer (score 27):

```
find . -name *foo* | xargs -r ls -lah
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you for that solution. But how can I deal with whitespaces?

Comment: @Lasall the preferred way is to use find's `-exec +` (or `-exec \;`). `xargs` is only safe to use with the `-0` option, which means that you have to tell whatever command you pipe to `xargs` to delimit the items with NULL-bytes (\0). With `find` you can do that with `-print0`. xargs's -0 and find's -print0 are not standard, but -exec is, so if portability is ever an issue, use find with -exec.

Comment: So simply brilliant! Thanks! Didn't know the "-r" before. Life saver!!

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
find  . -name *.bak -ls
```

Comment: I would just add the ability to ignore anything that isn't a regular file.  `find . -name '*.bak' -type f -ls`.

Answer (score 9):

This works with filenames with spaces or unusual characters, and `ls` can sort all the files:

```
find . -name *foo* -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lah
```

`-print0` means that filenames such as `file foo 1` will get output from `find` followed by null.  The "-0" argument to `xargs` tells it to expect this sort of input, so filenames with spaces get piped to the `ls` command correctly.

The `xargs` construction is in some ways better than `find etc -exec ls {} +` because all the filenames get sent to `ls` at once, so if you want to sort them all by timestamp (using `ls`), something like this works:

```
find . -iname *pdf -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr
```

On a NetBSD system, "-printx" is also an option (this seems a useful argument to me, but whatever, we have xargs -0 and it's okay):

```
find . -name *foo* -printx | xargs ls -lah` # not for Ubuntu
```

Comment: This did the trick for me for being able to actually use the sorting functions of ls, for those trying to do this.